# PROBLEMAS LIVEWIRE V3

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewire

Me encargaron un proyecto el cual cuando se ejecuta por php artisan serve funciona muy bien pero cuando se ingresar a traves de  la ip no funciona bien.

En la documentacion dicen que se debe cambiar las rutas a unas rutas custom para que livewire funcione, de esta maenra

```
    Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
        return Route::get('/crm-claro/vendor/livewire/livewire/dist/livewire.js',$handle);
    });
    Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
        return Route::post('/crm-claro/public/livewire/update', $handle);
    });
```

Con esto he logrado hacerlo servir pero esta pasando algo muy curioso por ejemplo estoy navenado en esta ruta dentro de la app:

```
http://127.0.0.1/crm-claro/public/crear-solicitud-lv-1
```

Y debo realizar un cambio y para ello uso un formulario que me actualzia una tabla, hasta ahi normal pero al actualizar me redirige a la ruta

```
http://127.0.0.1/crear-solicitud-lv-1
```

No se como hacer para que me redirija correctamente ya que cuando lanzo el servidor con php artisan serve vuelve al mismo sitio.